# locationManager didExitRegion never called for iBeaconRegion when monitor region

Tags: swift, monitoring, core-location, region-ranging

I've created region:

```swift
let uuid = UUID(uuidString: "04C7E2F3-42A5-5127-B066-502C8A27EB85")! 

beaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(uuid: uuid, identifier: uuid.uuidString)
```

And using [mbeacon](https://github.com/watr/mbeacon) from terminal created beacon from my MacBook.

Creating beacon with mbeacon: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsJDw.png).

In the method `didRangeBeacons` this beacon is detected and when I go far from the beacon, proximity increased and then the beacon is disappeared, but `didExitRegion` never called. Where is the moment, when this method should be called? Maybe I understand something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I checked locationManager.monitoredRegions and saw unnecessary regions here. I stopped monitoring (func stopMonitoring(for region: CLRegion) or you can simply uninstall the app and install it again, as this will clear the monitoring list.) for unnecessary regions and didExitRegion and didEnterRegion now work.